# JDK appears to install, but is not detected and commands don't work

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, cmd, installation

I just got a new computer at home. I've been trying to install JDK 8u11 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine all night. I know I downloaded the correct 64-bit version. I know I have JRE on my computer already, because `java -version` returns `java version "1.8.0_11"` in cmd. I can see both JRE and JDK in the Add/Remove Programs list. However, my IDE does not recognize that JDK is installed, and when I type `javac` in cmd, I get `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.` This leads me to believe that JDK is not actually installed, yet I've tried reinstalling and restarting several times, and like I said before, it shows up in Add/Remove programs. I also can see the \jdk1.8.0_11 file system in \Program Files\Java, right next to the \jre8 folder. The \jdk1.8.0_11 file system looks complete, of course except for the actual application jdk-8u11.exe (or similar file). That is nowhere to be found.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

NOTE: `JAVA_HOME` is not an environmental variable. I have tried to manually create the environmental variable, but the following paths did not work: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\java.exe

Comment: What `IDE` are you using? Add it to your tags.

Comment: Java Home should be the first one. Is a java entry like %JAVA_HOME%\bin (or C:\...\Java\jdk...\bin) in you PATH environment variable ?

Comment: You have to have the bin folder of the installation in your PATH variable

Comment: There is no java entry in my PATH environmental variable. What should I do?

Comment: add it by hand in system settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Windows 7:**
>
> 1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
> 2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
> 3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
> 4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. **If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.**
> 5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK. Note: You may see a PATH environment variable similar to the following when editing it from the Control Panel:
>
>    %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have installed a 64-bit version of JDK make sure you are using same bit version of NetBeans or eclipse (64-bits) in your case.

then set the environment variable in (MyComputer(Properties) -> Advanced System Setting -> Environment Variables )

Delete all the existing path of earlier tries of JDK as they may be overlapping 
 and create a new one.