# The Getting Started Tutorial (Error)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ibm-cloud

I'm sort of new to Bluemix.  I wanted to try to get the basic java application, located here:  https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/getting-started.html#clone

When I reched this step.. 
mvn clean install 
I'm getting the following error.  However, I have Java installed, Eclipse, Maven configured, etc... 
Installations:
-  jre-8u144-windows-x64
-  eclipse-inst-win64
-  maven with environment variables etc.

How do I get past this step?
also .. below that are my environment variables details..

[image: Start Screen Error]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that the JDK is required and not the JRE.  Install jdk-8u144-windows-x64 and try again.

For more information on the difference between the JRE and JDK, see [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

Comment: I installed this file... jdk-8u144-windows-x64  from this location:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
but I am still getting the same exact error.

Comment: Ensure the Jdk binaries are in the path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320625/jdk-appears-to-install-but-is-not-detected-and-commands-dont-work

Comment: I updated my qn with details of environment variables.. still no luck :/

Comment: What does it mean to ensure jdk binaries are in the path.. I read through but I just don't know what I am missing or what to look for..

Comment: the jdk binaries are usually in the \bin folder of the installed jdk. Ensure the bin folder is in your path.

Comment: added the bin folder path into my environment variables.. still getting the same error.  
It says no compiler is provided in this environment.. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK.. but I have a jdk!

Comment: Make sure you restart the terminal window or eclipse so that it sees the new path.  If in doubt, reboot windows.

Comment: Yess!! So I got a build success (removed and reinstalled everything) and did what you mentioned above.. very happy its working!  Btw, following these instructions on the Bluemix website:  https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/getting-started.html#getting-started-tutorial

Gonna continue with the rest of the steps.. but thank you so much!!!